# How add "CASE WHEN..." to has many relation in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Right Mysql request

```
SELECT  `task`.`type` AS `type`, `task`.`user_author_id` AS `user_author_id`
FROM `task_goal`
LEFT JOIN `user`
          ON `task_goal`.`user_author_id` = `user`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `task`
    ON (`task_goal`.`id` = `task`.`goal_id`) AND CASE WHEN `task`.`type` = 'personal' and `task`.`user_author_id` != `user`.`id`
     THEN `user`.`show_personal_task` = 1
     ELSE true
        END;
```

Yii2 request to task_goal and join HasMany relation "tasks"

```
$query = TaskGoal::find();
$query->select(['task_goal.*','task_goal.type AS goal_type'])->andWhere(['task_goal.active'=>true])
->joinWith([
'tasks'=>function(ActiveQuery  $itemQuery) {
    $itemQuery->andOnCondition(['task.active' => true]);
}]);
```

Relation

```
public function getTasks() {
return $this->hasMany(Task::class, ['goal_id' => 'id']);
}
```

How I can add CASE WHEN...

```
CASE WHEN `task`.`type` = 'personal' and `task`.`user_author_id` != `user`.`id`
                          THEN `user`.`show_personal_task` = 0
                           ELSE true
                     END
```

to "tasks" HasMany relation ?

Comment: Why use `CASE` in the on condition in the first place? You can rewrite your condition like this `task_goal.id = task.goal_id AND (user.show_personal_task = 1 OR task.type != 'personal' OR task.user_author_id = user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

When I test andOnCondition I added [ ] :) so don't

```
$itemQuery->andOnCondition("CASE WHEN `task`.`type` = 'personal' 
                              THEN `user`.`show_personal_task` = 1 and `task`.`user_author_id` != `user`.`id`
                               ELSE true
                         END");
```

And finely request

```
$query = TaskGoal::find();

    $query->accessFilter('goal')->select(['task_goal.*','task_goal.type AS goal_type'])->andWhere(['task_goal.active'=>true])
        //->select(["milestone_item.* as milestonessss"])
        //->leftJoin(['milestone_item' => $milestone ],'milestone_item.goal_id = task_goal.id')
        ->joinWith(['milestone' => function(ActiveQuery $q) {
            $q->select('task_milestone.*');
            $q->accessFilter('milestone')->andWhere(['task_milestone.active'=>true]);
        }])
        ->joinWith('userAuthor')
        ->joinWith([
        'tasks'=>function(ActiveQuery  $itemQuery) {
            $itemQuery->andOnCondition(['task.active' => true]);
            $itemQuery->joinWith('userAuthor');
            if (!empty($this->user_responsible_id_array)) {
                $itemQuery->andOnCondition(['task.user_responsible_id'=>$this->user_responsible_id_array]);
            }
            if (!empty($this->status_array)) {
                $itemQuery->andOnCondition(['task.status'=>$this->status_array]);
            }
            if (!empty($this->urgently)) {
                $itemQuery->andOnCondition(['task.urgently' => $this->urgently]);
            }
            if (!empty($this->influence)) {
                $itemQuery->andOnCondition(['task.influence' => $this->influence]);
            }
            if (!empty($this->name)) {
                $itemQuery->andOnCondition(['like', 'task.name', $this->name]);
            }

            if (!empty($this->deadline_start) && !empty($this->deadline_end)) {
                $itemQuery->andOnCondition(['>=','task.deadline',strtotime($this->deadline_start . ' 00:00:00')])
                    ->andOnCondition(['<=','task.deadline',strtotime($this->deadline_end . ' 23:59:59')])
                    ->andOnCondition(['!=','task.deadline',null]);
            }

            if (!empty($this->completed_date_start) && !empty($this->completed_date_end)) {
                $itemQuery->andOnCondition(['>=','task.completed_date',strtotime($this->completed_date_start . ' 00:00:00')])
                    ->andOnCondition(['<=','task.completed_date',strtotime($this->completed_date_end . ' 23:59:59')])
                    ->andOnCondition(['!=','task.completed_date',null]);
            }

            $itemQuery->andOnCondition("CASE WHEN `task`.`type` = 'personal' 
                          THEN `user`.`show_personal_task` = 1 and `task`.`user_author_id` != `user`.`id`
                           ELSE true
                     END");
    }]);
```